# How to display an image when selected and before saving it in the database?

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

As I said, I am trying to create an image when selected it shows me a preview image, before press the save button.

Something like this:

```
<div class="row align-items-center my-5">
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-4 mb-lg-0" src=" HERE WILL BE THE IMAGE SELECTED   " alt="">
      </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-8 -->
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Seleccionar!</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">IMAGEN 1</h2>
        <p class="card-text">Descripcion......</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="#" class="SELECCIONAR">More Info</a>  //When i press this button, i want to show a preview image in the field up beofore i press "Seleccionar!"...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the problem if you save it to the database then display it?

Comment: There is no problem if i do that because i know how to do it, but i just want to show a preview image before save it, and then save it with the submit button ( i dont know how can i do that)

Comment: In my project, I also want to show the image before saving it into the main Photo table but without saving the image I can not show it the UI why because I am using image uploading ajax code tht will show the image only when the JSON data(data fetched from Photo table after saving it) will come in response. So what I am doing is I am using one temporary photo table and saving image in it then I do some stuff and finally save the image into the main Photo table.

Comment: Well, i dont think that is the best way to do it. But is a solution for now. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: When we use some jquery file upload plugins they display the image only when the JSON response comes from the backend and that is only possible if you save the image in db. Without saving you can not send the JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @chirag soni was correct for me.

I had to upload a temporary photo, saving the image in it and finally save it in the database as usual.